# Hibernate exception when trying to connect users - Field 'username' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am trying to allow a user to follow another user but I am getting an error every time. When I insert it via SQL in my database it works, so it is the Java side that I am getting an error on. Here is my code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name = "roomie_username")
private String roomie_username;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName="username", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private User user;

public Roomie() {
    this.user = new User();
}

public Roomie(int id, String roomie_username, User user) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.roomie_username = roomie_username;
    this.user = user;
}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/user/{username}")
public String showUser(@PathVariable String username, Model model,
        Principal principal) {
    User user = usersService.getUser(username);

    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    Roomie roomie = new Roomie();
    roomie.setRoomie_username(username);

    model.addAttribute("roomie", roomie);

    List<Roomie> roomies = roomieService.getRoomies(username);

    model.addAttribute("roomies", roomies);


    return "user";

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addRoomie", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addRoomie(Principal principal,
        @Validated(value = FormValidationGroup.class) Roomie roomie)
        throws IOException {

    String currentUsername = principal.getName();
    if (currentUsername.equals(roomie.getRoomie_username())) {
        return "cannotadd";
    }
    else {
        roomie.getUser().setUsername(currentUsername);

        if(roomieService.exists(roomie.getRoomie_username(), currentUsername)) {

            return "cannotadd";
        } else {
            roomieService.saveOrUpdate(roomie);

            return "roomieadded";
        }

    }
```

In my JSP where I'm actually trying to add the roomie:

```
<sf:form id="details" method="post"
                action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addRoomie"
                commandName="roomie">
                <sf:input type="hidden" name="roomie_username"
                    path="roomie_username" />
                <input class="btn btn-default" class="control"
                    value="Connect to user" type="submit" />
            </sf:form>
```

My database structure:

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkAE3.png)

This is my error:

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC
>   exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [insert into
>   roomie (roomie_username) values (?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code
>   [1364]; could not insert: [com.spring.web.dao.Roomie]; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
>   insert: [com.spring.web.dao.Roomie]

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

We can enable the logging in hibernate layer to see the actual input passed to queries. Please refer the URL https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html.  Either you can configure by log4j properties or hibernate XML. It will help you to debug any issues

Comment: I have logging enabled but it just displays the same errors.

Comment: If you have logging enabled for org.hibernate package, you will definitely able to see the input values like name1, name2 in the next line of input query which was printed with ? Characters. Please check once again.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/JDBCException.html#getErrorCode().  Please printout the error code and note it and check with underlying database manuals to see more detailed information

Comment: Only errors displaying are as follows: WARN - SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
ERROR - Field 'username' doesn't have a default value